# 'Memory Full' while transferring large file using QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qtcpsocket

I'm trying to transfer a large file in a non-blocking fashion, by connecting `bytesWritten` to my function `sendNextBlock`.

```
void AsynchronousRetrieveCommand::start()
{
    connect(socket(), SIGNAL(bytesWritten(qint64)), this, SLOT(sendNextBlock()));
    sendNextBlock();
}

void AsynchronousRetrieveCommand::sendNextBlock()
{
    socket->write(file->read(64*1024));
}
```

I'm running this code on a Symbian phone, and after 5-6 megabytes have been transferred I'm getting "Memory Full" message box in the phone, and this message in the debug output:

```
[Qt Message] CActiveScheduler::RunIfReady() returned error: -4
```

I assume this is some kind of a memory leak, but I can't see what's causing it in my code.

Comment: How big is the file you are sending?

Comment: About 500 MB, but the error happens after only 5 MB have been transferred. But it shouldn't matter anyway, because I'm sending it block by block, and each block is only 64k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it turned out the socket's buffer was growing uncontrollably because data was being fed to it faster than it could be flushed.

I fixed the problem by checking the value given by `bytesWritten`, and writing only so much bytes (in effect, refilling the buffer back to 64k).

My fixed code now looks like this:

```
void AsynchronousRetrieveCommand::start()
{
    connect(socket(), SIGNAL(bytesWritten(qint64)), this, SLOT(sendNextBlock(qint64)));
    sendNextBlock(64*1024);
}

void AsynchronousRetrieveCommand::sendNextBlock(qint64 bytes)
{
    socket()->write(file->read(bytes));
}
```

Comment: You're missing some error handling, better use the ( char*, qint64) overloads of read/write and check the return value to make sure the data was actually read/written.

Comment: I was assuming that if I can't read the file then `QFile::open` would fail in the first place (and I have checks for that)

Comment: read/write((const) char*, qint64) return the number of bytes read/written. Not checking the return value can lead to data loss. Also, after opening the file, reading/writing can still fail (then returning -1).